# Is it possible to change wp7 app from paid to free from limited period?

Tags: windows-phone-7

Just wanted to know if it's possible to change an existing paid app to free app for a limited period in windows phone marketplace.

And then change it back to paid app after one week or so.

I've tried searching before and could only find that it's possible to change free app to paid but not above.

Thanks.

Comment: I guess it works both ways why wouldn't it. :) Only you need to wait for the certification process over again. :) I only made one of my app cheaper and that worked.

Comment: Why don't you make the app trial?

Comment: App trials cannot be permanently free, I'd like to give full version to few users for certain period.

Comment: End up implementing my own unlocking system for certain users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may make a paid app free, but it will cost you a "token" (you have 100 per year and submitting a free up costs one of them). After that you can switch back again.
Every price change may take a couple of hours until active. Also you cannot time those changes automatically.

Comment: 100? I though it's 5, next one 20$. Did the system changed?

Comment: Yes, they changed it last February: http://create.msdn.com/en-US/news/100_Free_Submissions

Comment: Couple of hours sounds good. I hope it doesn't takes time for complete certification.